# Could you help me fix this cross-compiling error with the QEMU for risc-v?

Tags: cross-compiling, qemu, riscv, spike

I'm trying to execute simple code in C. when I run the executable with this command :
**/opt/riscv32i/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-run code.elf** then I got the result. but when I ran it with qemu **/opt/qemu-riscv/bin/qemu-system-riscv32 -kernel code.elf** I got this error :
**qemu-system-riscv32: Unable to load the RISC-V firmware "opensbi-riscv32-spike-fw_jump.elf"**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the parameter -bios none.

```
/opt/qemu-riscv/bin/qemu-system-riscv32 -kernel code.elf -bios none
```